# como ajustar script function prinDIV y evitar impresion en un tabla de una seccion TD

Tags: javascript, css3, datatables

Estimados,

Este caso donde coloque un **script function printDiv** para poder imprimir solamente las tablas pero no funciona el **cellpadding** no ajustan. ¿como lo hago?

1) estoy tratando ajustar las celdas de las tablas que no separen, sino lineas justas.

2) otro problema; quiero evitar una sección **"Modificar"** no debe mostrar para impresión. solo las tablas seleccionadas. Ya lo intenté con hidden-print no resulto no funciona con TD. No quiero perder tiempo, quiero hacer corto.

ayudame...!! saludos..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de tu función aqui en lugar de la imagen, asi es mas facil para nosotros ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estoy tratando ajustar las celdas de las tablas que no separen, sino
>   lineas justas.

Para esto puedes usar `border-collapse: collpase` en los estilos de la tabla. Si la quieres con bordes, puedes usar `table th:not(:last-of-type)` (lo mismo para `td`) para darle un borde derecho de `1px`. También puedes darle a los `tr` (siempre y cuando no sea el último) un borde inferior de `1px` y a la tabla un borde general de `1px` también.

**Ejemplo**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
table thead th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
table thead th,
table tbody td {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: .5rem .65rem;
}
table thead th:not(:last-of-type),
table tbody td:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table thead tr,
table tbody tr:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table style="display: inline-block">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>J495MF3</td>
         <td>Vitaminas</td>
         <td>24.78</td>
         <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>04KFM4Q</td>
         <td>Shampoo EGO</td>
         <td>20.35</td>
         <td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

> Quiero evitar que la sección "Modificar" no debe mostrar
>   para impresión.

Veo que para imprimir copias el contenido de la tabla y lo escribes en otra pestaña. Si lo haces así, entonces basta que, en la tabla copiada le añadas un estilo `table th:last-of-type, table td:last-oftype` cuyo valor de `display` sea `none`.

**Ejemplo**

```
let tableHTML = '<style>'+
                  // tus estilos
                  'table th:last-of-type,' +
                  'table td:last-oftype { '+
                  '  display: none;' +
                  '}' +
                  '</style>';
tableHTML += document.getElementById('table').outerHTML;
let newWin = window.open('');
newWin.document.write(tableHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

Es posible que te quede el borde derecho de la tabla doble, esto es porque al eliminar la última columna la columna anterior conserva su borde derecho. Si lo quieres eliminar solo debes hacer (en la tabla a imprimir):

```
table th:nth-child(penúltima),
table td:nth-child(penúltima) {
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: gracias por tus datos, lo lei varias veces y acabo darme cuenta e hice otra forma. Me resulto bien. Gracias!